# How to verify in-app purchase with no user system and no server-side on android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, verification

I didn't find any definitive answer for my situation as all of this kind of questions revolve around server-side verification, which is irrelevant to me.

I'm trying to implement in-app billing in my app in order to offer the option of a premium upgrade. I've followed the guides in the developer documentation and done most of the work.
The problem is purchase verification:
The documentation suggests I shoud pass a developer payload to each purchase to uniquely identify the user - but my app doesn't have or need a user system - how can I uniquely identify a user without requiring user input or extra permissions?

Further and more important problem:
When the user makes a purchase, or opens the app after making a purchase in a different time, I need to verify this purchase - I don't have a server where I can send the purchase data to so it can verify it itself or using the Google Developer API.
It is my understanding that I shouldn't verify the purchase locally on the device (using the Google Developer API).

What is the best way for my situation to verify in-app purchases?
Is there a way to do it without a server? (I do not have the knowledge nor resources to have my own server)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you would go about verifying a digital purchase *without* a network connection. Thankfully though, you do not need a user account system nor do you need the knowledge and resources to have a dedicated server because that is what [Google Play services](https://developer.android.com/google/index.html) is meant for.

After setting up Google Play services; each user will be signed in through their Google Play account and be able to use their registered payment methods within your app when you implement the [In-app Billing API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). And you can test and manage all of this information from the [Google Play Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! However your answer is not helpful to me. I didn't say I need to verify purchase without a network connection, just that I don't own a server who I can use to verify purchase info queried from Google Play. I know Google Play Services takes care of the interface and billing, but my question is about the verification process that the developer is supposed to code.

Comment: @talZz As I mentioned in my answer, that is what the In-app Billing API is for. It handles the verification process for you; check [Implementing the API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't seem to get the problem.

Comment: use firebase with login and realtime database @talZz am i right? Bryan